# Algorithm to find maximum independent subgroup of hashmaps

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I need an algorithm to find a maximum independent subgroup of hashmaps, where it represented in an array of hashmaps.

I tried to go over the array of the hashmaps and send and index every time and see which hashmaps in  the array not independent with  the hashmaps in this index, it worked but in case of

```
A and B independent  
B and C independent  
but A and C can be not independent
```

**Definition of maximum independent subgroup of hashmaps:**

I have an array which contain hashmaps, every hashmap contain a key, every two hashmaps called independent if every key in the first hashmap is not contained in the second map so I have to find a subgroup of those hashmaps which all are independent

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "maximum independent subgroup" of hash maps? Maybe I'm just being dense right now.

Comment: @Dennis Meng I have an array which contain hashmaps, every Hashmap contain a key, every two hashmaps called independant if every key in the first hashmap is not contained in the second map
so i have to find a subgroup of those hashmaps which all are independent

Comment: @user3092193 Mind if you add that in the question? Finding something relevant to the question in the comments isn't always easy for people who stumble on this question.

Comment: Going back to this question, I'm first trying to convince myself that this isn't NP-complete (if I post an answer, i want it to be reasonably efficient unless I'm sure that "reasonably efficient" can't be done)

Comment: @DennisMeng I'm pretty sure this is NP-complete. Reduction from maximal independent set (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set): Take the given graph and create an array of hashmaps, one for each vertex. For each edge in the graph insert a new key value pair in both hashmaps, where the key is the same (so those two hashmaps are not "independent"). Then solve the problem in this question in polynomial time. You have now found the maximal independent vertex set in the original graph AND proved P = NP. Congratulations! You win $1000000.

Comment: @Sean Yep, sounds about right. You can even take it a step further and say that this question is *equivalent* to maximum independent set since you can also reduce the other way (create a graph with one vertex per hashmap, and edges between hashmaps/vertices iff they share an element).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this problem is NP-complete.
To prove this, suppose a graph, with indexed edges.
Create a HashMap for every vertex and fill it with indices for every incident edge of that vertex.
Then if two HashMaps are independent, they do not contain the same edge, therefore the respective vertices are independent as well.
Finding a maximum independent subset of these HashMaps hence gives you the maximum independent set in the graph, which we know is NP-complete.

You can solve this problem by constructing a graph, with a vertex for each HashMap and adding an edge for every two dependent HashMaps and then using some algorithm for independent sets.
Another way is to take the complement graph and finde max clique.

Since this is inefficient, you may consider using some approximation algorithm.